# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 39 bytes) in xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx

Tags: php, drupal-7, fatal-error

I have hosted one drupal website in godaddy. but now a days I am fighting with most weird problem "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 39 bytes) in xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx". I am beating my head against a wall to solve out that problem but nothing is useful for me. It always shows this error, whether I install new module,delete module,clear cache or add article etc, in almost all cases it shows allow memory size exhausted error. I also go through my php.ini file and change memory_limit = 128M but that error is not live me in drupal world. Please help to sort out this issue..

here is my phpinfo:

[image]

i already increased my memory_limit in php.ini from 64MB to 128MB, but it is not getting  reflected in my server. when i go to [https://www.ginfy.com.phpinfo.php](https://www.ginfy.com/phpinfo.php) still it is showing 64MB.

Comment: How does allocating 39 bytes exceed 64mb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The change u've made in your php.ini file has not been reflected because the allocated memory  67108864 bytes is 64MB.

Follow [Drupal Community Documentation](http://drupal.org/node/207036) increase the PHP memory limit. In Case of shared hosting please request the hosting provider to increase it.

Comment: i already spoke with hosting provider but they told that you have to minimize your modules instead of giving proper solution.. @Prem

Comment: 64mb is less for a drupal site. Did u try "php_value memory_limit 128M" in htaccess file

Comment: yeah @Prem, tried that one also, no solution yet.

Comment: better change your hosting provider

Answer (score 0):

add this in your php file

```
ini_set('set_memory_limit',-1);
```

Comment: thanks but i already tried it, still problem is there..

Comment: May be you are limited by the server's physical memory.?

Comment: we have unlimited memory space in godaddy.

Comment: If that is the case you have to increase the memory of server

Comment: but how we can do it, please can you tell me?

Comment: "unlimited memory space" is impossible. there is always a limit. also, be careful not to confuse memory space with storage space (which is more likely to be listed a 'unlimited', even though there may realistically be limits there too)

Comment: understand @Spudley, but right now how i solve this problem, why with every update of module or anything i do such error is coming.